# Diff between LoadViewState and TrackViewState Event in ASP.Net Page Life-cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, page-lifecycle

Exactly what happens in TrackViewState Page Event Method in ASP.NET. How it differs from LoadViewState.

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewState property is of type System.Web.UI.StateBag. The StateBag class provides a means to store name and value pairs, using a System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary behind the scenes.

The reason the StateBag has the TrackViewState() method is to keep the view state as trimmed down as possible. Again, we don't want to store the initial property values in the view state, as they don't need to be persisted across postbacks. Therefore, the TrackViewState() method allows the state management to begin after the instantiation and initialization stages.

for more info follow the subtittle
[Timing the Tracking of View State in this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)